# How to create a HTML5 Drag and Drop Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

*feel like this is kind of weird question but still*,

I want to create studio where people can create cards using different kind of contents, like Text, Images, Video, Audio, Links etc. and save them, so that I should be able to render them as they designed through some other view.

I am planning to built it with `ReactJS Framework`. I am new bee to `ReactJS`, just went through `TODO tutorials`. And done some work around to understand `Drag and Drop` features with `ReactJS`.

But I am still confused about **How** and **Where** to begin coding for my requirement. What should be the **structure** of my application. What all properties each components should have, totally got blocked.

I am not asking here exactly to give the structure for my application, I am looking for some resources/documents where it explains how to structure application for these kind of requirements.

Something like [beefree.io](https://beefree.io/) is what I want to build.

Many Many Thanks for all your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very recommend TinyMCE editor: https://www.tinymce.com/download/. This editor has a lot of features. I can also recommend http://hammerjs.github.io/, https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor and http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/.

If you want to create standalone HTML5 editor, you should research GitHub sources of recommended editors and learn mainly jQuery and AngularJS.

Instructions how to create from basics HTML5 editor:

- http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-make-browser-editor-with-html5-contenteditable/
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-an-html5-text-editor-with-the-filesystem-apis
- http://buildwithreact.com/

Comment: Thanks for all the references.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying out Unroll.io's react-email-editor: https://github.com/unroll-io/react-email-editor

It has a lot of features that you are looking for and is super easy to use in your web app. Also good documentation is available.

This React component is focused towards emails but if you plan to use it for HTML pages instead of emails, you can easily create a similar React component and change `displayMode` to `web` as per Unroll.io docs.

I have seen this being used in production on EmailMonster's [email editor](https://emailmonster.io).